# Trying to fetch ID from inside of repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Inside a repeater there's a list of addresses ..when address link button is clicked, the address is shown inside of
text boxes above repeater with all text boxes greyed out and an Edit button is rendered on the page OUTSIDE the repeater
and below the text boxes..Now how do I edit this address ?

I need the AddressID of the address that has been clicked inside the repeater...

when Address link is clicked,DisplayAddress command event is fired inside of repeater's ITemCommand so what I did was
 assigned "AddressID" generated(when Adress link was clicked inside repeater) to a globally decalred string variable 
 and tried to use that inside my Edit Button's click event so as to fill the
 Datasource(Method used to fill data source requires AddressID) and do stuff...didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stored the ID in Viewstate..It worked

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [LinkButton.CommandArgument Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx)

Comment: thnx for answering...have figured it out myself